# Clean up region extraction with RGB color masking

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, image-segmentation

I am developing a color masking algorithm to extract overlapped regions of interest in images, using `Python 3.9` and `cv2`.

To achieve this, I'm implementing K-Means clustering as a way to group up similar pixels and reduce the image's color palette to only a few hues. Then, I use `np.unique` to find the unique RGB values present, and I finally filter the original image with one of the values provided.

From the following image, I am able to sucessfully extract the region I want:

[image: Original Image]

Extracted Region:

[image: Extraction ROI]

As observed, the result still contains some noise from the underlying region (flame) around the area of interest. I have attempted to clean it up using `cv2.GaussianBlur` and `cv2.ConnectedComponentsWithStats`, but I can't seem to remove it properly. Below is my desired output (manually removed noise):

[image: Desired Result]

How can I achieve the same result (or similar) programatically?

Note: The RGB filter to extract this region can be defined as follows:

```
rgb = np.array([198, 154, 107])
# Making a range with 25% offsets
low = rgb * 0.75
high = rgb * 1.25
# Defining the mask
mask = cv2.inRange(image, low, high)
# Applying mask
result = cv2.bitwise_and(image, image, mask=mask)
```

Comment: Convert your kmeans result to white on black as a mask. Then get contours of the white regions. Then filter on area. Then apply the mask to remove the filtered regions in your kmeans color image.

Answer (score 1):

If you are set on selecting the interested area based on hue, consider converting your image to other color spaces like HSV or LAB as well. Perhaps even CMYK - 4 numbers to represent a color might separate browns from reds and yellows better.
Those may make it easier for you to find the "brown color" through clustering euclidean distance of pixel colors.

Alternatively, perhaps capturing the black stroke surrounding the chicken would be an easier task, as black is more distinct from red/yellow than brown is?